# How come the value in search textbox inside a form is saved

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search, razor

I am trying to implement search functionality in Asp.net MVC Razor. What i am finding strange is the retrieval of value in search texbox (though i want this, but will like to know whats happening under the hood).

Following is the HTML code :-

```
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    @Html.TextBox("query")
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                }
```

Here is the controller code :-

```
    public ActionResult Search(string query, int? page)
    {
        int pageIndex = page ?? 1;
        ViewBag.query = query;
        PagedList.IPagedList<Product> PagedProducts = dbStore.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(query)).ToList().ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize);
        return View(PagedProducts);
    }
```

**NOTE**:- The above HTML code resides on a shared _Layout.cshtml i.e. masterpage file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN article on [ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.aspx) is brief, to say the least, but it's `ModelState` that is responsible for this.

Once `@Html.BeginForm()` is processed, the controls are populated by the values from `ModelState` of the current model, if it's applicable.

You can override this behavior (and force clear the textboxes) by calling `ModelState.Clear()` in your action method.

Comment: I am unable to understand this. In other example where i have seen the use of forms which are posted back this doesn't happen.

Comment: Also, I tried this but still the text shows up in the search textbox

Comment: This contradicts my knowledge. Could you please provide a working sample to illustrate your situation?

Comment: I added the `ModelState.Clear();` and then commented the `ViewBag.query = query;` and it got cleared. It's strange, how come the form textbox retrieve the value from ViewBag. That's a weird thing, it automatically retrieves value from ViewBag for the same name

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay Yes, the default behavior will first look for a model property and then will look for a viewbag property that matches the parameter.  Since this happens automagically this can be confusing!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know `ViewBag` entries are also processed

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Model Binding, a built-in default feature of ASP.NET MVC.  With each request to the server the the Model Binder looks for form input values that match properties of objects or parameters of action methods within your controller.

For a more detailed explanation please review: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx